# Is it possible to call React from an html event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, d3.js

I am using the d3 drawing library with React.js, and have run into a problem with firing onClick events from SVG elements.

What I want to do is call a function (passed from parent in props) when I click on an element in the SVG. The problem is that the elements of the SVG are produced by d3, and are not react components. Is there any way that I can make this work?

For those not familiar with d3, it provides a very nice fluent syntax for generating and updating svg from a set of data. The code looks something like this:

```js
      const existingNodes = d3Select('.nodes')
        .selectAll('g.node')
        .data(root.descendants());
      const newNodes = existingNodes.enter().append('g');
      newNodes
        .append('circle')
        .attr('onclick', (node) => 'onNodeSelected("Test")')
        .attr('r', (node) => nodeRadius(node.data));
```

The problem with this code is the line that says `.attr('onclick', (node) => 'onNodeSelected("Test")')` which correctly adds an `onclick` attribute to the circles, but of course `onNodeSelected` is a prop of the react component and can't be accessed like this.

To provide some context, the abbreviated code for the React component is like this:

```js
export const HierarchyDiagram = ({ onNodeSelected, hierarchyData }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    function buildSvg(root) {
    ...abbreviated
      const existingNodes = d3Select('.nodes')
        .selectAll('g.node')
        .data(root.descendants());
      const newNodes = existingNodes.enter().append('g');
      newNodes
        .append('circle')
        .attr('onclick', (node) => 'onNodeSelected({node})')
        .attr('r', (node) => nodeRadius(node.data));
    ....abbreviated
    }

    if (hierarchyData) {
      buildSvg(hierarchyData);
    }
  }, [hierarchyData]);

  return (
    <svg width="100%" height="100%">
      <g className="wrapper">
        <g className="links"></g>
        <g className="nodes"></g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where did you place above code? in side component ?

Comment: I edited my question to provide more context for how this code is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to attach the `onclick` event use `on`. This should work:

```
.append('circle')
.on('click', (evt, node) => {
  onNodeSelected(node);
  d3.event.stopPropagation(); // stop the event propagation
});
```

Comment: This is very close, but not quite there. When I set a breakpoint I can see that `node` is of type `MouseEvent` but I need access to the data.

Comment: I found that `this.__data__.data` does give me access to the data and maybe a better hack than the hidden input solution. Is there a less hacky way to do this?

Comment: The event handler should be `(evt, node) =>` instead of `(node) =>`. I updated the answer, which now works as expected.

Comment: Yes, thank you!, I did not pay attention to the arguments part, but the answer looks much better now.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a horrible solution that does work. If anyone else can find a better solution then I will mark your answer as the correct one.

My solution was to add a hidden input and use it to pass the ID of the node that was clicked. This works because the child element (circle in the SVG) receives the click before the parent (events bubble up).

My abbreviated code looks like this:

```js
export const HierarchyDiagram = ({ onNodeSelected, hierarchyData }) => {
  const hiddenInputId = 'selected-node-id';

  useEffect(() => {
    function buildSvg(root) {
    ...abbreviated
      const existingNodes = d3Select('.nodes')
        .selectAll('g.node')
        .data(root.descendants());
      const newNodes = existingNodes.enter().append('g');
      newNodes
        .append('circle')
        .attr('onclick', (node) => 'getElementById("' + hiddenInputId + '").value="' + node.data.id + '"')
        .attr('r', (node) => nodeRadius(node.data));
    ....abbreviated
    }

    if (hierarchyData) {
      buildSvg(hierarchyData);
    }
  }, [hierarchyData]);

  function handleClick() {
    const hiddenInput = document.getElementById(hiddenInputId);
    const selectedNodeId = hiddenInput.value;
    hierarchyData.descendants().forEach((node) => {
      if (node.data?.id === selectedNodeId) onNodeSelected(node.data);
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input type="hidden" id={hiddenInputId} />
      <svg width="100%" height="100%">
        <g className="wrapper">
          <g className="links"></g>
          <g className="nodes"></g>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </>
  );
};
```